# AngularJS using ng-show based on grandson json element

Tags: json, angularjs

I have the following json data in my application:

```
{  
   "Success":true,
   "Error":null,
   "Data":{  
      "VersionId":1,
      "SecretaryId":1,
      "SecretaryName":"Foo",
      "Status":1,
      "Schools":[  
         {  
            "SchoolId":123456,
            "SchoolName":"Equipe de Desenvolvimento do Portal",
            "ContractStatus":1,
            "TotalTeachers":2,
            "TotalStudents":0,
            "Grades":[  
               {  
                  "GradeId":1,
                  "GradeName":"2º Year",
                  "TotalStudents":0,
                  "Classes":[  
                     {  
                        "SelectedYear":{  
                           "AvailableYear":null,
                           "Contract":null,
                           "Id":2,
                           "Canceled":false,
                           "EngagedAreas":null,
                           "Registrations":null
                        },
                        "Id":2,
                        "Name":"A",
                        "TotalStudents":20,
                        "TotalA3":1,
                        "StudentsPCD":"1,2,3"
                     },
                     {  
                        "SelectedYear":{  
                           "AvailableYear":null,
                           "Contract":null,
                           "Id":2,
                           "Canceled":false,
                           "EngagedAreas":null,
                           "Registrations":null
                        },
                        "Id":3,
                        "Name":"B",
                        "TotalStudents":25,
                        "TotalA3":0,
                        "StudentsPCD":"1"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "GradeId":2,
                  "GradeName":"3º Year",
                  "TotalStudents":0,
                  "Classes":[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "GradeId":3,
                  "GradeName":"4º Year",
                  "TotalStudents":0,
                  "Classes":[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "SchoolId":52640002,
            "SchoolName":"EscTesRelatDir",
            "ContractStatus":0,
            "TotalTeachers":0,
            "TotalStudents":0,
            "Grades":[  
               {  
                  "GradeId":1,
                  "GradeName":"2º Year",
                  "TotalStudents":0,
                  "Classes":[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "GradeId":2,
                  "GradeName":"3º Year",
                  "TotalStudents":0,
                  "Classes":[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I use this json to dynamically create some HTML.
For each school a *div* is created, this is the first level. For each grade in the school, a *table* is created, this is the second level. And for each class in the grade a *table row* is created, this is the third level.

I'm wondering how could I use the *ng-show* command to show the first level *div* only if the related school have at least one *class*.

I've searched a lot, but I couldn't find an answer yet.

**EDIT:**

Here is my html code.

```
<div ng-repeat="school in data.schools" ng-show="{{ school.Grades.<AnyClass?>.length > 0 }}">
    <h2>{{ school.SchoolName }}</h2>
    <span><strong>Total Teachers:</strong> {{ school.TotalTeachers }}</span>
    <table ng-repeat="grade in school.Grades" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" ng-show="{{ grade.Classes.length > 0 }}">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">{{ grade.GradeName }}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th>Total Students</th>
                <th>Total A3</th>
                <th>PCD Students</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="class in grade.Classes">
                <td>{{ class.Name }}</td>
                <td>{{ class.TotalStudents }}</td>
                <td>{{ class.TotalA3 }}</td>
                <td>{{ class.StudentsPCD }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
This is how I'm making my requests:

```
//rest_client.js
"use strict";

(function(){
    var restClient = angular.module("restClient", ["ngResource"]);
    var serviceURL = "/habileapp/api/";

    restClient.factory("RegistrationResource", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
        return $resource(serviceURL + "Registration", null, {
            "get": {
                "method": "get"
            },
            "save": {
                "method": "post",
                "url": serviceURL + "Registration/Save"
            },
            "finalize": {
                "method": "post",
                "url": serviceURL + "Registration/Finalize"
            }
        });
    }]);
})();

//part of app.js
RegistrationResource.get({
    "idAplicacao": 1,
    "idSecretaria": 1
}, function (data) {
    if (data.Success) {
        $scope.data = data.Data;
        runApplication();
    } else {
        toastr.error(Errors.Code1);
    }

    hideLoading();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible within your template since you cannot bubble up through the different `ng-repeat`s. But you could add another attribute to each `school` object whether its `Classes` array length is greater than 0 within your controller:

```
//part of app.js
RegistrationResource.get({
    "idAplicacao": 1,
    "idSecretaria": 1
}, function (data) {
    if (data.Success) {
        angular.forEach(data.Schools, function(item) {
            angular.forEach(item.Grades, function(item2) {
                (item2.Classes.length > 0) && item.show = true;
            });
        });
        $scope.data = data.Data;
        runApplication();
    } else {
        toastr.error(Errors.Code1);
    }
    hideLoading();
});
```

Then, just add `ng-show="show"` in your markup.

Comment: this is not possible for me, since this data comes from an external service

Comment: Well, how do you request/get this data?

Comment: please share your request code. If you are doing an AJAX call, just paste my code into your `.then()` function

Comment: @andre doesn't matter where the data comes from, once you receive it you can do whatever you want with it

Answer (score 1):

After getting the data you can change it or add any "helper" properties that you can use to control the elements you want to show or how to show them. Consider the following example which makes any entry red that has a "long title", being more than 40 characters:

HTML template

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <b><u>Posts</u></b>
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <span ng-class="{ 'red': post.longTitle }">
      id:{{ post.id }} title:{{ post.title }}
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  // get data
  $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    // take top 10
    var data = response.data.slice(0, 10);   

    // add helper property called "long title" that
    // doesn't exists in original data
    angular.forEach(data, function(current) {
      current.longTitle = current.title.length > 40 ? true : false;
    });

    // apply
    $scope.posts = data;
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

Result

[image]